# Вопросы о ClassLoader.getResources()

Tags: java, рефлексия

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Есть пакет `com.johnson.gameserver.community`

В пакете 4 (пока, дальше больше будет) класса. Первый класс - обработчик, остальные реализаторы интерфейса.

Есть нужда инстанциировать все классы в обработчике(синглетоне) в мапу.

Для этого, как я понял, требуется использовать нечто подобное:

```
try {
            Enumeration<URL> clazzez = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("com/johnson/gameserver/community");

            while (clazzez.hasMoreElements()){
                cont += "<br1>" + clazzez.nextElement().getFile();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Проблема в том, что энумератор содержит только ссылку на сам пакет (папку).

Подскажите, как правильно извлечь ссылки на все классы внутри пакета.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вы хотите собрать в мапу все классы пакета или же все классы, реализующие ваш интерфейс?

Comment: В мапу я хочу собрать экземпляры классов, которые дополняют базовый класс.

Сейчас делаю так:

`  // XXX Reflection
  Basic_CBF m;
  m = new CBF__Show();
  _modules.put(m.getBaseLink(), m);
  m = new CBF_SkillLearner();
  _modules.put(m.getBaseLink(), m);`

Comment: А что у Вас Basic_CBF - интерфейс/абстрактный класс/класс ?

Comment: Абстрактный класс

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В библиотеке Google Guava 14 есть класс ClassPath, который может сильно помочь в решении данной проблемы:

```
private static Collection<IHandler> loadHandlers() throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Collection<ClassInfo> classes = ClassPath.from(IHandler.class.getClassLoader()).getTopLevelClasses("com.johnson.gameserver.community");

    ImmutableList.Builder<IHandler> handlers = ImmutableList.<IHandler> builder();

    for (ClassInfo classInfo : classes) {
        Class<?> clazz = classInfo.load();
        if (!IHandler.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            continue;
        }

        // fitler out non instantiable types
        if (Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers()) || Modifier.isInterface(clazz.getModifiers())) {
            continue;
        }

        handlers.add(clazz.newInstance());
    }

    return handlers.build();
}
```

Comment: А вот за это - спасибо большое!

Конечно, всю либу тянуть вряд ли есть смысл, но у гугла, обычно, есть сорцы. Поковыряюсь.

Comment: Вообще guava очень хорошая либа. Если для вас размер приложения не критичен, то настоятельно рекомендую подключить. На их странице есть отличное описание возможностей библиотеки: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейс, абстрактный класс с логикой, 3 интерфейса с дефолтными конструкторами (будут подтянуты) и один без (будет пропущен).

Как лежат в файловой системе (содержимое `package`):

```
AbstractHandler.java
Handler1Impl.java
Handler2Impl.java
Handler3Impl.java
IHandler.java
NoDefaultConstructorHandler.java
```

результат:

```
handler = Handler1Impl
handler = Handler2Impl
handler = Handler3Impl
```

interface:

`public interface IHandler {}`

несколько имплементаций:

```
public class Handler1Impl extends AbstractHandler {}
public class Handler2Impl extends AbstractHandler {}
public class Handler3Impl extends AbstractHandler {}
public class NoDefaultConstructorHandler
{
    public NoDefaultConstructorHandler (String a)     
}
```

abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler implements IHandler
{
    private static final Package PACKAGE = IHandler.class.getPackage () ;

    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return getClass ().getSimpleName () ;
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        for ( IHandler h : getHandlers () )
        {
            System.out.println ( "handler = " + h ) ;
        }
    }

    public static List < IHandler > getHandlers ()
    {
        List < IHandler > result = new LinkedList < IHandler > () ;
        loadHandlers ( result, PACKAGE ) ;
        return result ;
    }

    private static void loadHandlers ( List < IHandler > result, Package packagee )
    {
        // get fso url
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource ( packagee.getName ().replace ( '.', '/' ) ) ;

        // get fso ref
        File dir = new File ( url.getPath () ) ;
        if ( !dir.isDirectory () )
        {
            return ;
        }

        File [] files = dir.listFiles () ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < files.length ; i++ )
        {
            // filter out non-files
            if ( !files [i].isFile () )
            {
                continue ;
            }

            // filter out non-class files
            String name = files [i].getName () ;
            if ( !name.endsWith ( ".class" ) )
            {
                continue ;
            }

            String className = name.substring ( 0, name.length () - 6 ) ;

            try
            {
                loadClass ( result, packagee.getName (), className ) ;
            }
            catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
            {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }

    private static void loadClass ( List < IHandler > result, String packageName, String className ) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {

        Class < ? > clazz = Class.forName ( packageName + '.' + className ) ;
        if ( !IHandler.class.isAssignableFrom ( clazz ) )
        {
            return ;
        }

        // fitler out non instantiable types
        int modifiers = clazz.getModifiers () ;
        if ( Modifier.isAbstract ( modifiers ) || Modifier.isInterface ( modifiers ) )
        {
            return ;
        }

        try
        {
            Object instance = clazz.newInstance () ;
            result.add ( (IHandler) instance ) ;
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот способ я рассматривал, но мне казалось, что в джаве можно это было сделать чуть проще...